# Water me. Give me water. Serve me with water

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-choice

> Water me.
>   Give me water.
>   Serve me with water.

Which one is correct?

I say, “Water me.” This is good English. What are the differences between these options?

Comment: I think the best way would be to say Can I get some water or Can I get a glass/cup of water?

Comment: _I say, Water me. This is good English._ No it is not (Unless you are an impolite plant.)

Comment: @Dude HOW DARE YOU SAY CAN INSTEAD OF MAY?! SEIZE HIM!

Comment: @JoShmo Stop screaming in my ears! :-)

Comment: May I have some water? This is making me thirsty.

Comment: You could use "Can i get some water"

Answer (score 12):

"Water me" sounds like you are asking someone to water you like a plant (you obviously don't want them to start spraying you haha).

"Give me water" and "serve me with water" mean the same thing but they can be impolite because you are commanding someone to do something for you. If you are asking someone for water it would be better to say "May I have water?"

Comment: But you **do** hear people say "beer me". "Serve me with water" just sounds weird.

Comment: To me (as a native speaker of American English,) "May I have some water?" or "May I have a glass of water?" would sound less awkward than just "May I have water?" but any of those is certainly better than the others (for the reasons you've mentioned.) As far as "beer me," that's intentionally incorrect usage for humorous effect.

Answer (score 5):

It will be very funny if you say "water me", because you water plants.You also water animals, which means you give water to them to drink.

Give me water is OK if you are ordering someone to give you water. To be polite, you should say "Please give me water".  The last sentence  "Serve me with water" also has an imperative tone like the second sentence and sounds unidiomatic.  You can say serve somebody with water but using the verb for yourself sounds a bit weird.

Comment: This is the more accurate one IMO. I'd only add that "water me" works in some forms of colloquial speech. "Water me" "beer me" "tea me" are all very informal (and very impolite with anyone but close friends). Being colloquial it's likely also not very universal. I hear this often with my close friends from the American Midwest, but I don't know how recognizable it is elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

If you aren't a plant, saying "water me" is generally not appropriate. Besides being slightly rude because it's a command rather than a request, it's just not how we ask for a glass of water. A plant (should it gain the ability to speak) could say this, similarly to the famous "[Feed Me Seymour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L7SkrYF8lCU)" song in *Little Shop of Horrors*.

In very casual conversation, I've heard people say "Beer me!" meaning "give me a beer" but it is not standard conversation and one generally wouldn't say it if you were talking to a waiter, for example.

What do people say?

> May I have a [glass of] water?
>   May I have some water?
>   I'd like a [glass of] water [please].
>   I'd like some water [please].

The statement:

> Give me some water.

Is a command. If you said this to someone, it could be taken as quite rude (assuming you weren't royalty of some sort).

And this one:

> Serve me with water.

Is not only a command (and falls into the same issues as the other two), but it's not idiomatic at all. It sounds like someone is asking to be served **using** water, which makes no sense and sounds impossible.